# Response with status of Moved Temporarily and no body

Tags: grails, soap, groovy, httpresponse

I'm using [groovy-wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite) on Grails to send a SOAP request to Service Stream. However the response I get back is empty.

I think I'm connecting to the server since I get a `302` status, or does that `302` status mean that I'm not connecting to the server?

I've tested sending to other services like http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx?wsdl, and it works just fine.

Does anyone have any idea what that `302` means or why I'm getting an empty response body?

Comment: A search for [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) would tell you most of what you need to know.  The server is responding with a redirect.  Maybe you are using an old URL.

Comment: There's actually a working cpp version of this. I'm just porting it to grails. I'm using the same url as the cpp version. Is there any other reason why the server would send a redirect?

Comment: It may be sending a redirect to the CPP implementation too. I cannot think of any reason that the calling client's underlying language/framework should affect whether the web server responds with a `302`. The CPP implementation may just handle it as I described in my answer. If you run the two clients side-by-side, do they yield different results? Or have you just confirmed that the CPP client worked previously? Have you tried logging the raw HTTP request/response that each implementation sends/receives? That should tell you what is happening straight from the horse's mouth as it were.

Comment: I can't run the cpp client since I don't have the authorities to run it, but I can try to ask for a log of the http request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are connecting to the server.  [HTTP response status 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) indicates a redirect - that the resource identified by the URL has been (temporarily) moved to another URL.

The response body is empty because the response's `Location` header has all the relevant information to go along with the response code - the resource's new URL.

Basically, just send an identical follow-on request to the URL that comes back in the `Location` header when you get a `302` response.

Comment: This was the response inside the Location header: `http://www.donotcall.gov.au:80/CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc?method=getcfcinhtml&name=dncrtelem.rtw.washing&path=/dncrtelem/rtw/washing.cfc`

Does that look normal?

Comment: At first `donotcall` threw me off, but `donotcall.gov.au` is just the host name for the Austrailian Communications and Media Authority (or ACMA)'s [Do Not Call Register](https://www.donotcall.gov.au/); and `.cfc` indicates (taken at face value) a ColdFusion Component.  So that seems like a reasonable `Location` value to me.

Comment: I don't understand what that method=getc‌​fcinhtml&name=dncrtelem.rtw.washing&path=/dncrtelem/rtw/washing.cfc means. I also tried to replace the url with this and it still responds with a 302.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the URL you provide to the `SOAPClient` is the service URL and not the URL to the WSDL document.  It's possible that since you are trying to POST to the WSDL it's attempting to redirect you to the actual service URL.  Examine the WSDL and find the service URL (usually at the bottom) and use that.  Most times if the URL you are using ends in `?wsdl` or `.wsdl` you can simply remove that in order to get the service URL.

Comment: Still not working. I think it has something to do with the library I'm using. I'll just try sending raw xml.